# UDP multicast client over ipv6

Tags: debian, socket, udp

> [Simple Python UDP Server: trouble receiving packets from clients other than localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734219/simple-python-udp-server-trouble-receiving-packets-from-clients-other-than-loca)

I am trying to listen datagrams over ipv6. Here are the messages I am interrested in:

```
$ sudo tcpdump | grep 20001
[sudo] password for miroslavv: 
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
13:00:59.981338 IP6 fd01:e671:2015:5c01:a00:27ff:fe50:275f.20001 > ff05:e671:2015:5c01:a00:27ff:fe50:275f.20001: UDP, length 86
13:00:59.981348 IP6 fd01:e671:2015:5c01:a00:27ff:fe50:275f.20001 > ff05:e671:2015:5c01:a00:27ff:fe50:275f.20001: UDP, length 47
13:00:59.981733 IP6 fd01:e671:2015:5c01:a00:27ff:fe50:275f.20001 > ff05:e671:2015:5c01:a00:27ff:fe50:275f.20001: UDP, length 114
13:00:59.981744 IP6 fd01:e671:2015:5c01:a00:27ff:fe50:275f.20001 > ff05:e671:2015:5c01:a00:27ff:fe50:275f.20001: UDP, length 67
13:00:59.981940 IP6 fd01:e671:2015:5c01:a00:27ff:fe50:275f.20001 > ff05:e671:2015:5c01:a00:27ff:fe50:275f.20001: UDP, length 60
13:00:59.982276 IP6 fd01:e671:2015:5c01:a00:27ff:fe50:275f.20001 > ff05:e671:2015:5c01:a00:27ff:fe50:275f.20001: UDP, length 47
13:00:59.982492 IP6 fd01:e671:2015:5c01:a00:27ff:fe50:275f.20001 > ff05:e671:2015:5c01:a00:27ff:fe50:275f.20001: UDP, length 47
13:00:59.982656 IP6 fd01:e671:2015:5c01:a00:27ff:fe50:275f.20001 > ff05:e671:2015:5c01:a00:27ff:fe50:275f.20001: UDP, length 47
13:00:59.982974 IP6 fd01:e671:2015:5c01:a00:27ff:fe50:275f.20001 > ff05:e671:2015:5c01:a00:27ff:fe50:275f.20001: UDP, length 69
13:00:59.982985 IP6 fd01:e671:2015:5c01:a00:27ff:fe50:275f.20001 > ff05:e671:2015:5c01:a00:27ff:fe50:275f.20001: UDP, length 111
13:00:59.983335 IP6 fd01:e671:2015:5c01:a00:27ff:fe50:275f.20001 > ff05:e671:2015:5c01:a00:27ff:fe50:275f.20001: UDP, length 152
```

My platform is Debian testing. I tried the python [examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example), which seem to communicate perfectly with each other on the same machine. Yet, when the server is configured to listen for the above listed datagrams, it hangs in `recv()`.

Firewall settings:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
[sudo] password for miroslavv: 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I have an ipv6:

```
$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.42.92  netmask 255.255.248.0  broadcast 192.168.47.255
        inet6 fd01:e671:2015:e3ff:219:fff:fe26:a27e  prefixlen 48  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::219:fff:fe26:a27e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:19:0f:26:a2:7e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3360785  bytes 943676498 (899.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 6185  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 473236  bytes 77103917 (73.5 MiB)
        TX errors 1  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 140  bytes 7912 (7.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 140  bytes 7912 (7.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`netcat` is also silent:

```
$ netcat -u -l -p20001
```

A peculiar observation is the following. I managed to get some C++ code to read messages **if** at the same time `boost::asio` is reading from the same ip and port. Should boost polling be stopped, my code also stops receiving messages.

I already tried a bunch of example C programs, but am unable to receive even one UDP packet from anyone: [1](http://ntrg.cs.tcd.ie/undergrad/4ba2/multicast/antony/example.html), [2](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15213-f99/www/class26/udpserver.c), [3](https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/417/notes/sockets/udp.html), [4](https://gist.github.com/tuxmartin/e64d2132061ffef7e031).

What is going on here?

Comment: The issues is probably me not joining a multicast group. Will post a more detailed answer once the whole thing works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I was missing joining the multicast group. With examples about ipv6 multicast rather scarce, here is tested code:

```
struct addrinfo hint {}, *res;
hint.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
hint.ai_family = AF_INET6;
hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
getaddrinfo( server._rep.c_str(), std::to_string( port ).c_str(), &hint, &res )
mreq.ipv6mr_multiaddr = reinterpret_cast<  sockaddr_in6* >( res->ai_addr )->sin6_addr;
mreq.ipv6mr_interface if_nametoindex( iface.c_str();
setsockopt( _fd, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (void*)mreq, sizeof( mreq ) )
```

PS: Some helpful resources on the subject:

http://www.iitk.ac.in/LDP/HOWTO/Multicast-HOWTO.html#toc6

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-4415/sockets-149/index.html